# My entire website is showing a blank screen on Bing and Google's cached crawls

Tags: css, google-cache

I just noticed that my website, www.dupure.com, just shows a blank screen when I look at the cached information on both Bing and Google.  Here's two links:

- [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NbRB3_vqfTYJ:www.dupure.com/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)
- [Bing cache](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=dupure&d=4602110628922030&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=4dERyY0E86UszDC_mGKdlWeLVYJMU4VN)

Because I'm using CSS throughout, could there be something in there?  I was thinking an issue in robots.txt, but I don't even see that file.

Comment: Use Google's fetch tool instead since pages not rendering on the cache doesn't reflect on your rankings.

Comment: It is somehow related to the CSS.  If I view the source code of the Google cache, your content is there.  If I click the "Text-only version" link on the Google cache, it shows your content.

Answer (score 6):

I narrowed it down to a simple test case:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<script src="http://www.dupure.com/scripts/plugins/modernizr.min.js"></script>
HELLO WORLD
```

The div with the relative position is inserted by Google cache and ends up enclosing both the modernizr script and the page contents.  The modernizr script does something that prevents all the sibling content from displaying when in this container.  Other people have encountered this same issue:  [Google Cache snapshot Issue #1086](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1086)

You appear to be using modernizr version 2.5.3.  Upgrading to the latest version of modernizr fixes the problem.  "Hello World" shows up on the page in this case:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
HELLO WORLD
```

Answer (score 2):

I speculate that this is a markup issue within your HTML and HEAD, since 
Google's and Bing's cache are more sensitive to markup issues due to the fact they will scrape your `<html>` and `<head>` and inject their own markup.

*Browsers correct invalid markup successfully, well most times...*

If your code has issues within these fields the browser has a harder time correcting the issue. You see invalid markup doesn't normally create a huge issue because nowadays browsers are so much better at correcting the issue, however when Bing and Google get involved, it makes a issue, worse.

*Caching not a SEO factor*

The good news is that Google and Bing do not use the cache as a ranking factor and is purely designed for users wanting to see a cache version of the page, should it be updated or because the website is down.

*However...*

While SEO and the fact that most browsers will correct the errors, this doesn't mean all browsers will, older browser are more likely going to be effected. If you take a look at the source of the Google cache you will see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<base href="http://www.dupure.com/"><style type="text/css">body { margin-left:0;margin-right:0;margin-top:0; }#google-cache-hdr {background:#f5f5f5 !important;font:13px arial,sans-serif !important;text-align:left !important;color:#202020 !important;border:0 !important;margin:0 !important;border-bottom:1px solid #cecece !important;line-height:16px !important ;padding:16px 28px 24px 28px !important;}#google-cache-hdr * {display:inline !important;font:inherit !important;text-align:inherit !important;color:inherit !important;line-height:inherit !important;background:none !important;border:0 !important;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;letter-spacing:0 !important;}#google-cache-hdr a {text-decoration:none !important;color:#1a0dab !important;}#google-cache-hdr a:hover { text-decoration:underline !important; }#google-cache-hdr a:visited { color:#609 !important; }#google-cache-hdr div { display:block !important;margin-top:4px !important; }#google-cache-hdr b {font-weight:bold !important;display:inline-block !important;direction:ltr !important;}</style><div id="google-cache-hdr"  dir=ltr><div>This is Google&#39;s cache of <a href="http://www.dupure.com/" dir="ltr">http://www.dupure.com/</a>. It is a snapshot of the page as it appeared on 13 Sep 2016 14:32:44 GMT. </div><div>The <a href="http://www.dupure.com/" dir="ltr">current page</a> could have changed in the meantime. <a href="http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&amp;p=cached&amp;answer=1687222">Learn more</a></div><div></div><div><span style="display:inline-block !important;margin-top:8px !important;margin-right:104px !important;white-space:nowrap !important;"><span style="margin-right:28px !important;"><span style="font-weight:bold !important;">Full version</span></span><span style="margin-right:28px !important;"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NbRB3_vqfTYJ:www.dupure.com/&amp;num=1&amp;client=firefox-b&amp;hl=en&amp;gl=uk&strip=1&vwsrc=0">Text-only version</a></span><span style="margin-right:28px !important;"><a href="http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NbRB3_vqfTYJ:www.dupure.com/&amp;num=1&amp;client=firefox-b&amp;hl=en&amp;gl=uk&strip=0&vwsrc=1">View source</a></span></span><span style="display:inline-block !important;margin-top:8px !important;color:#717171 !important;">Tip: To quickly find your search term on this page, press <b>Ctrl+F</b> or <b>⌘-F</b> (Mac) and use the find bar.</span></div></div><div style="position:relative;">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Take notice of the 2x `<!DOCTYPE>` this will bound to cause issues with a lot of browsers. Currently the front page has [36 Errors, 2 warning(s) reported by W3C](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dupure.com%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) Validation. Browsers are not correcting the markup as shown in the screenshots below... take notice to the invisible fields (empty white space), these shouldn't exist.

[image: Invalid Markup Bing Cache]

[image: Invalid Markup Google Cache]

*Summary*

Not all the 36 errors will be causing this issue, however its more likely going to be those outside of the body, but you should attempt to fix all to rule those out.

Comment: The double doctype is caused by Google.   They keep the doctype from the original and insert their own before it.   The issue is is with the `<div style="position:relative;">` that Google inserts and incompatibility with the modernizr JavaScript.

Comment: Not true I checked that with my own view-source:http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1LOmiH9nowMJ:https://www.bybe.net/&num=1&client=firefox-b&hl=en&gl=uk&strip=0&vwsrc=0 before I posted this. The fact is both BING and GOOGLE reports an invisible space within Firebug, this is generally caused by incorrect markup. It's not a styling issue as most CACHING issues are, if you look through his code in firebug, none of his actual content is listed in the HTML, only view source, again this is post-processing, pre-processing the data is their, which would indiciate a markup issue.

Comment: That's not a doctype through?

Comment: Yes, there are bad tags, but I think they are all caused by Google.  It appears to be modernizr that is making text invisible somehow.

Comment: Try and find his content in HTML view post-processing. If it was position:relative you would see it within the HTML view. It's not invisible, its not actually there at all. Checked loads lol, I was determined to find it but its not there :)

Comment: I'm not sure how the modernizr javascript could do that, but it appears to.  See the test cases I put in.

Comment: At first I thought maybe he had a extra </div> and closing the content before the contentCache or the div position:relative, but the only fault I can see it is markup. Strange problem but other than that I dunno. Oh modernizr can do this because its before the content, so you most likely right

Comment: But then again... if you disable JS... it doesn't render either... surely disabling JS would fix the issue completely? since no elements are being hidden and no data is actually there when rending with a browser.. EDIT: Actually.... your completely and utterly right... renders perfectly without JS enabled! I swear this was the first thing I check doh! what a waste of my time lol